# How to extract data from a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a long list of coordinates defined in some 8D space.  I need to extract the first three coordinates only.  How ?

For example :

```
coords = {{0.1, 0.4, -0.2, 1.2, 3.2, 0.5, 0.8, 2.2}, ...};
```

I need to define the list of all first three components :

```
reducedCoords := {{0.1, 0.4, -0.2}, ...}
```

Please, notice that I'm working with *Mathematica 7*.

Comment: `Take[#, 3] & /@ coords` takes first three elements from each sublist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is core functionality:

```
coords = Table[Range[5], {3}]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}

```
coords[[All, 1 ;; 3]]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}

Comment: beat me by 2 seconds!

Comment: Ok, it's working.  Thanks a lot !